# Can we invent English words based on similar usage? Ex, "can you eat a mouse" or ".. eat mouse"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Now, if you study dictionaries, you see that an animal or poultry is a countable noun when you refer to a living thing.
For Example,

> [fish](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fish_1?q=fish) [countable] a creature that lives in water, breathes through
>   gills, and uses fins and a tail for swimming
>
> *They caught several fish.*

but an animal or poultry is an uncountable noun when you refer to its flesh as food

> [fish](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fish_1?q=fish) [uncountable] the flesh of fish eaten as food
>
> I like frozen/smoked/fresh fish

However, we don't have this pair "count - uncount noun" for all animals in English because English people don't eat these kinds of animal. But people in other countries do.

For example,

> [mouse](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mouse_1?q=mouse)(n): a small animal that is covered in fur and has a long
>   thin tail. Mice live in fields, in people’s houses or where food is
>   stored.
>
> a field mouse

We have no "**mouse**" as **an uncountable noun that refers to its flesh as food.**

So, **Can we invent English words based on similar usage?**

We can invent a new word "**mouse**" as **an uncountable noun that refers to its flesh as food.**

> Eg, which one is correct?
>
> can you eat a mouse? (this sounds like you eat it raw???)
>
> can you eat mouse?

I don't want to mean we eat it raw. I mean we can cook it before eating it (ie, **we see it as a kind of food** like fish or chicken).

**Note**:  I noticed that people often put "**meat**" before these not-considered-for-eating animals. For example, "**dog meat**", "**cat meat**".....

**DO you think that it is safer to put "*meat*" before these not-considered-for-eating animals?**

**Extra question:**

**I am not sure if it is wrong** to say:

"**I eat 2 chickens & 3 fish**" since chicken or fish is considered as an uncountable noun when we see it as a kind of food.

Comment: Since, at least in the US and Europe, it's not common to eat mouse flesh, dictionaries don't list "mouse" as an uncountable noun.  But used in that sense it is -- you might (if you're ever invited to a Donner party) eat "mouse" or "cat" or "dog'.  There is nothing wrong with this usage (even if you object to the diet).

Comment: First off, _ew!_  Second, birds are animals, last time I checked.  Anyway, yes, you can use the countable form for food -- _Costco sells fresh rotisserie chicken; I bought three chickens!_  As for _would you like some more mouse and potatoes?_  sure, it works fine.  I don't think it's a hard and fast rule about specific animals, but more about the context -- If you were really crazy, you might have grilled brick for dinner or maybe sauteed book.  I think this also applies (more normally) to plants -- I might pick an artichoke and then we would have artichoke for dinner.

Comment: @HotLicks Mouse was certainly on the menu in the Pax Romana of Europe. A recipe in Latin (Apicius) exists for the preparation and cooking of a dormouse.

Comment: By 'Can we invent English words based on similar usage?' you mean 'Is massification of animal names when referring to eating the animal's meat a totally productive feature in English?'  If there's an idiomatic plural alternative (I've never eaten snails / cockles / mussels ...), I'd stick with that. Using say 'We were eating helmetshrike / gnateater / Australasian babbler / pardalote / gerygone // carpsucker / hammerjaw // sloth' sounds quirky or worse, and these are probably better rephrased. But massification _is_ very common, and certainly hereabouts.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I found a lot of "eat dog meat", so the safest way is to put "meat" before "dog", "mouse".....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Careful -- you might have to eat crow.

Comment: @Hot Licks ... and watch the pounds fly off?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [Can we invent English words based on similar usage? Ex, "can you eat a mouse" or ".. eat mouse"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/133930/48032)

Comment: Lots of Anglophones eat things like oysters and snails, but they don't normally say *I eat oyster* or *I like snail*, just as people would only say *I eat pig* facetiously. It's just that there are a few words that can apply to both the whole animal *and* its flesh considered as food *(chicken, fish, lamb, rabbit,...)*

Answer (score 3):

You can use the uncountable form even for animals that are not typically considered food.

PolitiFact ran an article titled *[In context: Obama's comments on eating dog in Indonesia](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/article/2012/apr/20/context-obama-dog-eating-indonesia/)*.

Similarly, in [an interview](http://www.metroactive.com/bohemian/11.15.06/dining-0646.html) Anthony Bourdain states: "I'm not eating rat under any circumstances."